# How to upload a file in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to upload a jpeg file (2.1Mb) using react-images-upload, however, when I save the received file on backend, it has 7.5 Mb. Could anyone give me suggestions to understand what's wrong?

```
<ImageUploader
  withIcon={true}
  buttonText="Choose the Document"
  onChange={onDrop}
  maxFileSize={5242880}
  idealResolution={{ width: 640, height: 480 }}
  isMaxResolution={true}
/>
```

and the handle function:

```
const onDrop = (documentFiles, documentDataURLs) => {
const document = documentFiles.pop();
document.arrayBuffer().then((arrayBuffer) => {
dispatch(
   submitDocument(
      [{ name: document.name, bytes: new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer) }],
          submitDocumentCallback
        )
      );
    });
  };
```

In the backend, I'm justing saving the bytes using a FileOutputStream.

Comment: What is ImageUploader component?

Comment: Sorry, this's the import: import ImageUploader from "react-images-upload";

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the source code for react-images-upload and have to say that it doesn't look like something I'd want to put in production.

I also don't see how you actually make it upload to the server. Your example doesn't include where you specify the server URL.

For uploading files in React, I'd go with something more robust. I'm biased toward [react-uploady](https://github.com/rpldy/react-uploady) (since it's my project). So I'd recommend it. But there are other good ones as well (I guess).

For example, with react-uploady, its as simple as:

```js
import React from "react";
import Uploady from "@rpldy/uploady";
import UploadButton from  "@rpldy/upload-button";

const MyApp = () => (
    <Uploady destination={{url: "https://my-server.com/upload"}}>
        <UploadButton/>
    </Uploady>
);
```